# How to deny read access to a file for all users except a group in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I want to protect a file in TFS (not even read access).
Do we have an option in Team Foundation Server to hide a file from all except for a particular group?

Comment: Can you add what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit the permissions for that single file you can change the reader and contributor groups from "inherit" to "not inherit". You can then change all of the permissions for all of the groups to "not configured" to remove permission without denying. Then add your special group and set "allow"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can deny all permissions of a particular group for a specific with TFS 2013.

Use the Source Control Explorer to find the file of interest. Right click on that file and select "Advanced - Security...". A "Properties for " window will be displayed with the "Security" tab selected. Select the group of interest from those listed [or create it if it does not yet exist]. Then in the "Permissions section, select the "Deny" checkbox for all permissions starting with the "Read" permission.

The "Deny" permission has precedence over the "Allow" permission, so this should enable you to obtain the desired end result.

Comment: Unfortunately as deny overrides allow you can't enable for only a single group.